# ChartJS Searching chart Type for positioning a Point onto a bar (range)

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to migrate this chart made by excel into chartJS:
[image]
important features:

- having a horizontal bar showing a range
- let range be from 'lower' (0%) til 'upper' (100%)
- median is shown in by a vertical line (50%)
- place one single point somewhere on the range (e.g. at 23%)
- the single point is the only dynamic component here, everything else always looks the same

I know thats not a typical chart and a bit special.

Closest charts I found are:
1)

- a simple stacked bar chart were instead of the bright obvious star I just another bar-stack
- not very pretty the same
  [image]

2. 

- a mixed chart
- with an line using the annotations plugin (here I draw the line with paint by hand)
- in css the whole chart needs to be rotated by 90° (already done in the image shown below)
  [image]

3. 

Another option my be creating it by using plane css stuff. But Id rather make it using chart js since there are some more charts and all my framework is made for it.

Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charts.js allows you to access the canvas and draw custom stuff, using a simple mechanism.

We could start with just the bar, as a horizontal bar chart with one item and most other stuff disabled:

```js
const data = {
    labels: [""],
    datasets: [{
        label: '100%',
        data: [100],
        backgroundColor: '#4af',
        barThickness: 100
    }]
};
const options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
        animation: {duration: 0},
        indexAxis: 'y',
        layout: {
            padding:{
                left: 10,
                right: 10
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                display: false
            },
            y: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip:{
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
};

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.0/chart.umd.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="height:250px; width: 90vw; border: 1px solid #ddd "></canvas>

</body>
```

Now we can access the canvas through a plugin a draw all the rest:

```js
const plugin = {
    id: 'customDraw',  // to identify the plugin in the chart options
    afterDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
        const {ctx} = chart;
        // read plugin options
        const lineWidth = options.lineWidth || 1,
            lineColor = options.lineColor || '#000',
            textColor = options.textColor || '#000',
            textFont = options.textFont,
            starAt = options.starAt,
            starColor = options.starColor || '#f44';
        // get pixel coordinates for our bar, that is
        // positioned at y = 0, from x = 0 to x = 100
        const yCenter = chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(0),
            yTop = yCenter-50,
            yBottom = yCenter+50,
            x0 = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(0),
            x50 = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(50),
            x100 = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(100),
            xStar = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(starAt);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x50, yTop);
        ctx.lineTo(x50, yBottom);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = starColor;
        drawStar(ctx, xStar, yCenter, 10);

        ctx.textBaseline = "top";

        ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
        if(textFont){
            ctx.font = textFont;
        }

        ctx.textAlign = "start";
        ctx.fillText("Lower", x0, yBottom + 2);
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("Median", x50, yBottom + 2);
        ctx.textAlign = "right";
        ctx.fillText("Upper", x100, yBottom + 2);

        ctx.restore();
    }
};
```

Full code:

```js
    function drawStar(ctx, x0, y0, radius){
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043598/16466946
        const nSpikes = 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(let i = 0; i < nSpikes*2; i++){
            let rotation = Math.PI/2;
            let angle = (i/(nSpikes*2))*Math.PI*2+rotation;
            let dist = radius*(i%2)+radius;
            let x = x0+Math.cos(angle)*dist;
            let y = y0+Math.sin(angle)*dist;
            if(i === 0) {
                ctx.moveTo(x, y);
                continue; //skip
            }
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    const plugin = {
        id: 'customDraw',
        afterDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
            const {ctx} = chart;
            // read plugin options
            const lineWidth = options.lineWidth || 1,
                lineColor = options.lineColor || '#000',
                textColor = options.textColor || '#000',
                textFont = options.textFont,
                starAt = options.starAt,
                starColor = options.starColor || '#f44';
            // get pixel coordinates for our bar, that is
            // positioned at y = 0, from x = 0 to x = 100
            const yCenter = chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(0),
                yTop = yCenter-50,
                yBottom = yCenter+50,
                x0 = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(0),
                x50 = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(50),
                x100 = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(100),
                xStar = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(starAt);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x50, yTop);
            ctx.lineTo(x50, yBottom);
            ctx.stroke();
    
            ctx.fillStyle = starColor;
            drawStar(ctx, xStar, yCenter, 10);
    
            ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    
            ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            if(textFont){
                ctx.font = textFont;
            }
    
            ctx.textAlign = "start";
            ctx.fillText("Lower", x0, yBottom + 2);
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.fillText("Median", x50, yBottom + 2);
            ctx.textAlign = "right";
            ctx.fillText("Upper", x100, yBottom + 2);
    
            ctx.restore();
        }
    };

    const data = {
        labels: [""],
        datasets: [{
            label: '100%',
            data: [100],
            backgroundColor: '#4af',
            barThickness: 100
        }]
    };
    const options = {
        type: 'bar',
        data,
        options: {
            animation: {duration: 0},
            indexAxis: 'y',
            layout: {
                padding:{
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    display: false
                },
                y: {
                    display: false
                }
            },

            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltip:{
                    enabled: false
                },
                customDraw:{
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    textFont: '20px serif',
                    starAt: 23
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: [plugin],
    };

    new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-B51MzT4ksAo6Y0TcUpmvZnchoPYfIcHadIaFqV5OR5JAh6dneYAeYT1xIlaNHhhFAALd5FLDTWNt/fkxhwE/oQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="myChart" style="height:250px; width: 90vw; border: 1px solid #ddd "></canvas>
</body>
```

Next step would be to add custom interaction - tooltips, click events and everything...