# How to do a round tick marks in ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

Are there ways to make X axis tick marks round in ChartJS?
All I've managed so far is to make them into dashes, but that's not what I need.

The first screenshot is how I want it to look, the second is how I've managed to do it so far. I looked through the library documentation and couldn't find any prameter responsible for the shape of the tick marks. Maybe someone knows a way that can help me?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Since I cannot see any comfiguration for making the Tick round https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/TickOptions.html I suppose you'll need to create a 0 valued transparent line I guess?!

Answer (score 0):

Custom ticks can be drawn by extending the scale class used by the chart, as described in the the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/developers/axes.html). In particular, to draw circular ticks on a linear axis one may override the `drawGrid` method of `LinearScale`:

```js
class LinearScaleWithRoundTicks extends Chart.LinearScale{
    static id = "linear-roundTicks";
    drawGrid(chartArea) {
        const optionsGrid = this.options.grid,
            optionsTicks = this.options.ticks;
        let drawTicks = false;
        if(optionsGrid.display && optionsGrid.drawTicks){
            optionsGrid.drawTicks = false;
            drawTicks = true;
        }
        super.drawGrid(chartArea);
        if(drawTicks){
            optionsGrid.drawTicks = true;
            const ctx = this.ctx;
            const items = this._gridLineItems;

            for(const item of items){
                const tickR = optionsTicks.radius ?? 4,
                    fillColor = optionsTicks.backgroundColor ?? 'black';
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(item.tx1, item.ty1, tickR, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.restore();
            }
        }
    }
}
Chart.register(LinearScaleWithRoundTicks);
```

used as in the example below:

```js
class LinearScaleWithRoundTicks extends Chart.LinearScale{
    static id = "linear-roundTicks";
    drawGrid(chartArea) {
        const optionsGrid = this.options.grid,
            optionsTicks = this.options.ticks;
        let drawTicks = false;
        if(optionsGrid.display && optionsGrid.drawTicks){
            optionsGrid.drawTicks = false;
            drawTicks = true;
        }
        super.drawGrid(chartArea);
        if(drawTicks){
            optionsGrid.drawTicks = true;
            const ctx = this.ctx;
            const items = this._gridLineItems;

            for(const item of items){
                const tickR = optionsTicks.radius ?? 4,
                    fillColor = optionsTicks.backgroundColor ?? 'black';
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(item.tx1, item.ty1, tickR, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.restore();
            }
        }
    }
}
Chart.register(LinearScaleWithRoundTicks);

const nPoints = 15;
const datasets = Array.from({length: 2},
    (_, dataSet)=>({
        data: Array.from(
            {length: nPoints},
            (_, i)=>({
                x: i+1,
                y: 2+Math.cos((-i*4*(dataSet+1))/nPoints)+Math.random()/5
            })
        ),
        tension: 0.3,
        label: 'Set '+(dataSet+1),
        borderWidth: 1
    })
);
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {datasets},
    options: {
        scales:{
            x: {
                type: 'linear-roundTicks',
                ticks:{
                    radius: 4,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
                },
            }
        },
        animation: false
    },
};
new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);
```

```html
<div style="min-height:400px">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

There is here a "mixin vs inheritance" problem: the solution above only works for linear scales; if a chart has multiple types of axes, e.g., category, time, linear, one would have to extend all the classes of used scales. Extending the base case `Scale` would not work since the derived classes (e.g., `CategoryScale`) use the original class, not the extended one. That's why a mixin is a solution that works for any type of axis, although seems much hackier.

In the example below, the `drawGrid` is changed (only once per axis) in its [`beforeDataLimits` callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks). Thus different drawing functions, `drawXTick` and `drawYTick` are given for each of the axes, one linear and the other categorical.

```js
function mixIn_tickDraw(scale, drawTick){
    if(!scale.customTickDraw){
        scale.customTickDraw = true;
        const super_drawGrid = scale.drawGrid;
        scale.drawGrid = function(chartArea){
            const optionsGrid = this.options.grid,
                optionsTicks = this.options.ticks;
            let drawTicks = false;
            if(optionsGrid.display && optionsGrid.drawTicks){
                optionsGrid.drawTicks = false;
                drawTicks = true;
            }
            super_drawGrid.call(this, chartArea);
            if(drawTicks){
                optionsGrid.drawTicks = true;
                const ctx = this.ctx;
                const items = this._gridLineItems;

                for(const item of items){
                    drawTick(ctx, item, optionsTicks);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawXTick(ctx, tick, optionsTicks){
    const tickR = optionsTicks.radius ?? 4,
        fillColor = optionsTicks.backgroundColor ?? 'black';
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(tick.tx1, tick.ty1, tickR, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawYTick(ctx, tick, optionsTicks){
    const tickR = optionsTicks.radius ?? 4,
        fillColor = optionsTicks.backgroundColor ?? 'gray';
    ctx.save();
    const nSpikes = 5;
    //draw star, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043598/16466946
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i = 0; i < nSpikes*2; i++){
        let rotation = Math.PI/2;
        let angle = (i/(nSpikes*2))*Math.PI*2+rotation;
        let dist = tickR * (1+ i%2);
        let x = tick.tx1 + Math.cos(angle)*dist;
        let y = tick.ty1 +Math.sin(angle)*dist;
        if(i === 0) {
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            continue; //skip
        }
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

const nPoints = 15;
const datasets = Array.from({length: 2},
    (_, dataSet)=>({
        data: Array.from(
            {length: nPoints},
            (_, i)=> 2+Math.cos((-i*4*(dataSet+1))/nPoints)+Math.random()/5
        ),
        tension: 0.3,
        label: 'Set '+(dataSet+1),
        borderWidth: 1
    })
);
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: nPoints}, (_, i)=>'L'+(i+1)),
        datasets
    },
    options: {
        scales:{
            x: {
                ticks:{
                    radius: 4,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(16,92,78,0.7)'
                },
                beforeDataLimits(scale){
                    mixIn_tickDraw(scale, drawXTick);
                }
            },
            y: {
                ticks:{
                    radius: 4,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.9)'
                },
                beforeDataLimits(scale){
                    mixIn_tickDraw(scale, drawYTick);
                }
            }
        },
        //animation: false
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);
```

```html
<div style="min-height:400px">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```